# How do I factor this code into the 'factory' paradigm?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Here's the code I have in my models.py file, sitting at the very bottom, as per [this guide](http://sqlalchemy-searchable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html):

```
db.configure_mappers()
db.create_all()
db.commit()
```

This will execute at import time. So now, whenever I import a model, I get the following message:

`RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no applicationbound to current context`

I'm not sure how to factor this code into the factory paradigm. I tried to wrap the code in a function, and then call it in `create_app`.

When I do that, this is the error I get:

`sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: (in table 'ad', column 'search_vector'): Compiler <sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.base.SQLiteTypeCompiler object at 0x7f81bfc14940> can't render element of type <class 'sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base.TSVECTOR'>`

The search_vector column is pretty simple, taken from the sqlalchemy-searchable quickstart guide:

`search_vector = db.Column(TSVectorType('title', 'body'))`

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct — wrap initializing code in a function:

```
from models import db

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    db.init_app(app)
    db.configure_mappers()
    db.create_all()
    db.commit()

    return app

app = create_app()
```

Or if you want to avoid cluttering your launch file define the function taking application as parameter (models.py):

```
def init_db(app):
    db.init_app(app)
    db.configure_mappers()
    db.create_all()
    db.commit()
```

And use the function to initialize application:

```
from models import init_db

app = Flask(__name__)
init_db(app)
```

But your error is caused by another problem: SQLite does not support TSVector, it is PostgreSQL specific feature. All examples for SQAlchemy-Searchable are written for PostgreSQL databases.

It also looks like SQLite does not have full text search out of the box. Perhaps you need to switch to another DBMS.